# Bubbling and Capturing in context of addEventListener() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

in `addEventListner(event,function,useCapture)` method, `useCapture` parameter is two type bubbling and capturing.

My question is what is the function/operation of this `useCapture` parameter in context of js `addEventListener()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter(useCapture) of the `addEventListener()` method is decided in which way
the event is propagated in the html DOM.

this parameter has an boolean value,false indicates bubbling and true indicates capturing.
It is optional parameter and its default value is false.

Event propagation is a way of defining the element order when an event occurs.
Suppose you have a **h1** element inside a **div** element.Now if user clicks the **h1** element, 
then which element's "click" event will be handled first?

**In *bubbling*** the inner most element's event will be handle first then the outer.
i.e.**h1** element's "click" event will be handled first, then the **div** element's event will be handled.

**In *capturing*** the outer most element's event will be handle first then the inner.
i.e.**div** element's "click" event will be handled first, then the **h1** element's event will be handled.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram from [the DOM events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) may help shed some light:

[image: DOM events event flow diagram]

As you can see from that, there are three phases to an event: The *capturing* phase, which originates at the very top level view and works its way down to the descendant element the event is aimed at, then the *target* phase which occurs just on the target element, and finally the *bubbling* phase where it goes back up the hierarchy back to the root view.

The vast majority of the time, you only need or want to work with the bubbling phase (and IE didn't even support the capturing phase until IE9). Whether this is necessarily because it's more useful is a question; we're all just really used to it, and it's been the focus of continued innovation (cancelling bubbling and such), because (again) for years and years it was the only game in town if you wanted to support IE. And it *does* make good sense, but then, so does capturing.

---

The reason this exists is primarily a quirk of history. Very early on, of course, there were not specifications for this, and the dominant browsers at the time (Netscape Navigator and Microsoft Internet Explorer) both made up what they did with events. Netscape went with the "starts at the root and makes its way to the final target" (capturing) approach, Microsoft went with the "starts at the target and works its way to the root" (bubbling) approach. So when it came time to standardize this, the DOM committee decided to go with...both.